# Google trusted store badge not showing in all browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-trusted-stores

The Google trusted store badge in not showing across browsers and platforms.

I can get it to show in Safari Mac but not Chrome or Firefox Mac.

I can get it to show in IE Win and Firefox Win but not Chrome Win.

I went through [Google's implementation tips](https://support.google.com/trustedstoresmerchant/answer/3329097?hl=en).

Doctype checks out.

Google's Tag Assistant validates on the page.

The test, Test Drive, of the js implementation in Trusted Stores works fine.

robots.txt is also delivered under ssl.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google response:

> We are writing to you because we noticed a posting your team made asking about the Trusted Stores badge visibility on your site.
>
> I can confirm that your account, qxxxxxxxxxxxxxe.com, is in good standing. The badge is not displaying for half of users due to a few-week experiment we are running with all merchants in the program.
>
> We run experiments from time to time, as we are always looking to improve the user experience with your site and the program. For example, we have made improvements to the badge design and behavior, such as only opening the flyover on click (instead of mouseover).